# Setters on a model depends on the value of the other model

Tags: c#, oop, dapper

I have a stored procedure which returns one result set but has the fields with customer, orders, and pricing data. In my Model, I separated the model objects customer, orders, and pricing and I created a Model binder to bind all the object in one model. Now, the setters in pricing model depends on the returned value of the customer baseprice. How can I achieve the setters? By the way im using dapper for object mapping

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int baseprice {get; set;}
}

public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Pricing
{
    int _price;
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Price
        { get { return this._price; }
          set { this._price = Customer.baseprice * 10 }
        }
}


public class CustomerModelBinder
{
    public Customer Cust{get; set}
    public Order order{get;set}
    public Pricing pricing{get; set}
}

CustomerModelBinder cust = new CustomerModelBinder();
//put value to cust here......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Pricing class hold Customer class, it'll be simple.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BasePrice { get; set; }
}
public class Pricing
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Price => Customer.BasePrice * 10;
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

You can find how to put query results into such class in [this post](https://taylorhutchison.github.io/2016/03/23/dapper-orm-complex-queries.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that since you are creating instances.  You could do it in the `CustomerModelBinder` constructor.  Note, you need to set the `Customer baseprice` first.

```
public class Pricing
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerModelBinder
{
    public Customer Cust{get; set}
    public Order order{get;set}
    public Pricing pricing{get; set}
    public CustomerModelBinder(int custBasePrice)
    {
        Cust.baseprice = custBasePrice;
        pricing.Price = Cust.baseprice * 10;
    }
}
```

Or you could do the multiplication in `Pricing Price`

```
public class Pricing
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    private int _price;
    public int Price
    {
        get => _price;
        set
        {
            _price = value * 10;
        }
     }
}

public class CustomerModelBinder
{
    public Customer Cust{get; set}
    public Order order{get;set}
    public Pricing pricing{get; set}
    public CustomerModelBinder(int custBasePrice)
    {
        Cust.baseprice = custBasePrice;
        pricing.Price = Cust.baseprice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I did this but I have an error in Dapper mapping when my model has a constructors.